# leader keys are just being disabled when changing it

Tags: spacevim, leader

I am using Vim with SpaceVim, and I am trying to change the leader keys as explained by the [SpaceVim wiki page](https://spacevim.org/documentation/). But what is happening is that the leader keys are just being disabled.

I am using VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 in OpenSUSE 15.3.

`init.toml`:

```
[options]
    colorscheme = "PaperColor"
    colorscheme_bg = "dark"
    enable_guicolors = true
    statusline_separator = "arrow"
    statusline_iseparator = "bar"
    buffer_index_type = 4
    windows_index_type = 3
    enable_tabline_filetype_icon = false
    enable_statusline_mode = false
    statusline_unicode = false
    vimcompatible = true
    bootstrap_before = 'config#before'
    bootstrap_after = 'config#after'

[[custom_plugins]]
repo = 'NLKNguyen/papercolor-theme'

[[layers]]
  name = "format"
  format_method = "codefmt"
```

`autoload/config.vim`:

```
function! config#before() abort
  " Leaders
  let g:leader = ","
  let g:localleader = "."
  " Buffer Manage
  nnoremap <leader>bd<space> :bdelete<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>bd!       :bdelete!<CR>
  nnoremap <leader>B         :buffers<CR>
endfunction

function! config#after() abort
endfunction
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the global variables that need to be changed are actually [`g:mapleader`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapleader) and [`g:maplocalleader`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#maplocalleader), so you're missing the `map` prefix there.

Not sure why what you're seeing is “leader keys are just being disabled”, but perhaps this is enough to fix your issue.